# Configure Microsoft Exchange email on Ubuntu

Tags: email, configure

I want to configure Microsoft Exchange emails on Ubuntu the way I use it in Outlook on Windows XP. Please help me to find a good step by step article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By looking at your question, I'm quite unsure whether you exactly need Exchange itself or if it's just POP/IMAP which would be fine. Having said that, Exchange servers usually support POP and IMAP connections if I'm not mistaken. In which case, you can use clients like Thunderbird, Entourage.. etc. Nevertheless, this will not give the complete experience of the Exchange services. Anyhow, If you're to make a use of POP/IMAP service, it should be allowed from the Exchange side.

Now coming back to Exchange configuration; I've not tested it completely but **[Evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution#Evolution-EWS_.28Exchange_Web_Services.29)** worked well with mine.

## Installation

Installing the client is pretty straightforward and available to install in official repo's (*but I would still recommend to add your Ubuntu version when posting a question which will help us to assist better*). Simply open the **Ubuntu Software Center** and search for **Evolution**, then hit on install as seen below.

[image: Ubuntu Software Center - Evolution install]

## Email Configuration

Email configuration is pretty straightforward too. You can go through the process of adding a new mail account just like you do it on a Microsoft Outlook client. Meanwhile, I've found a video log on [**Connecting Evolution (On Ubuntu 11.10) to Exchange 2010**](http://youtu.be/EqU7ZZPo9Og) which may help you to further understand.

**P.S.** I do not know your Ubuntu version nor the Exchange version you're using. But above said process would follow the same mostly.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying Evolution but in the drop down list I cannot see option for Exchange. Is there anything missing? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: There should be.. Have a look into this > http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000378.htm

Comment: Thanks. I missed installing one package. Now I can see Exchange MAPI. When I start adding server, and domain etc details then on pressing Authenticate button I get an error message "cannot create mapi folders in offline mode". I don't know what does it mean. It is step # 9 in above link.

Any help?

Comment: It looks like using Evolution is the best solution. The ExQuilla plugin for Thunderbird is not free and not perfect. Be sure to install `evolution` and the exchange plugin `evolution-ews`

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu, by default, has the Mozilla Thunderbird e-mail client in it. Open up Unity's search bar, and search for "Thunderbird" (sorry if this sounds like a n00b). You can install plugins in Thunderbird to enable MS Exchange.

1. Open up Thunderbird.
2. Go to Tools>Addons.
3. Type **ExQuilla** in the Search field.
4. Install ExQuilla.
5. Now exit and restart Thunderbird.

Now go to Tools-you will see ExQuilla in the options-and follow the steps to connect to Microsoft Exchange.

You have to consider that this is not a free tool:

> Thunderbird email accounts, including contacts, connecting to Microsoft Exchange Web Services. This is a 60 day trial of a paid add-on.

License update:

> Previously this required a paid license. Versions 52 and earlier still require a license, but beginning in March 2018, those licenses are distributed automatically without charge. Upcoming version 60 will not require a license.

Comment: License is only $10/yr for a single user at this point. That sounds worth giving it a 60 day trial to me.

Comment: Install and setup was dead simple. I've tried and failed at the Evolution method before, but this does autodetect flawlessly for my access. I expect I can expense this $10, but I'm likely to buy it even if I can't at this point. Already looks better than OWA.

Comment: this solution works sharming

Comment: Even after expiration, you can use free session licenses by requesting one through the settings every time you start up Thunderbird (https://twitter.com/exquilla/status/516625541898579969)

Comment: ExQuilla is good, but it has one massive problem: every time you open your Exchange account, ExQuilla insists on re-downloading *everything* in every mail folder. With a large mailbox, this slows the entire system to a crawl, perhaps for several hours, even on a fast connection. I have emailed them about this but had no reply. It makes it unusable for large corporate mailboxes with thousands of messages in many folders. It also saves the password without asking and without being able to disable it, making it insecure on laptops. So nice, but not usable on big mailboxes.

Answer (score 6):

Try [www.hiri.com](http://www.hiri.com)
(I'm one of the founders) We built it exactly for this. Hiri can be installed in the Ubuntu Software app.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not a client you can install, but you can [use Outlook in your web browser now](https://outlook.office365.com). It supports most everything you would have in a regular desktop client. This works well under Ubuntu and other Linux flavors.

Comment: I've just paid $20 for an Hiri annual license. We'll see how it goes.